# Export list to csv file using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to export a list that is like that

```
    [{'Header1': 'Ahmed', 'Notes': 11.96},
 {'Header1': 'Salah', 'Notes': 16.13},
 {'Header1': 'Reda', 'Notes': 20.83}]
```

I could use csv module like that

```
with open('Output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
fc = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=results[0].keys(),)
fc.writeheader()
fc.writerows(results)
```

and that worked fine
How can I use pandas for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` by constructor and then use [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
L =   [{'Header1': 'Ahmed', 'Notes': 11.96},
       {'Header1': 'Salah', 'Notes': 16.13},
       {'Header1': 'Reda', 'Notes': 20.83}]

 df = pd.DataFrame(L)

 df.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Amazing. I expect you to reply to my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which is better using pandas or csv module?

Comment: @YasserKhalil - It is really complex question, it depends. If need only write data and no processing, I choose csv module. If need processing data I choose pandas.